# I have got location using NETWORK_PROVIDER

Tags: android, networking, location

In my App I am  getting location using `NETWORK_PROVIDER` but after uploading apk file to google play store,it shows the permission fine(GPS) location. I have a device which don't have GPS, I am not able to install the app from google play but i can install it manually. I am not getting any solution.It shows apps is not compatible.

Answer (score 0):

You must remove the

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permisssion.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
```

from your manifest. and only have `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION`. Even if you never use it in your code, Play store still uses it to filter out incompatible devices.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't explicitly indicate which hardware features your app requires, Google Play will make some assumptions based on the permissions your app has requested.

If you don't require GPS for your application, you need to indicate that GPS is not required by adding this to your manifest:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" android:required="false"/>
```

Note: you can use the following command line to see how Google Play will filter your application, based on declared (or implied) features and permissions:

`aapt dump badging <path_to_exported_.apk>`

All this (and more) is described pretty clearly in the [Google Play Filters documentation](http://developer.android.com/google/play/filters.html).